# Find all global solutions for minimization problem

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

Find all global solutions for the unconstrained problem

$\min_{x_1,x_2}f(x_1,x_2)=2x_1^2+x_2^2-2x_1x_2+x_1^3+x_1^4$

Now I'm a little bit confused. This is a problem from optimization class. Do I need to find the minima of this function or do I need to find all $f$ that have this minimum? In the first case I get the minimum at $(0,0)$ but since this problem asks for all solutions I'm not sure if there are more.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is that notation your attempt at a short hand description of the problem, or is that exactly how the problem was stated? In either case, in my opinion, someone is badly abusing the conventions of mathematical notation. Is this abomination supposed to mean that $f(x_1, x_2) =2x_1^2+x_2^2-2x_1x_2+x_1^3+x_1^4$, and you are looking the the values of $x_1, x_2$ that provide the minimum value for $f$?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's meant to look for the minimum values of $f$ although I agree that the notation is not very sensible. Now I have evaluated a local minimum at $(0,0)$. However I'm not sure how to prove that is also a global minimum?

Comment: The main problem with the notation is that it does not say that $f$ is the expression on the right, it says that $\min f$ is equal to the expression on the right. That is idiocy, in part because the LH side does not even depend on $x_1$ or $x_2$, which appear in it only as dummy variables. As for your question, you find extremums of smooth functions like this by finding mutual zeros of the partial derivatives. A bit of a pain since one of them is a cubic, but how to solve a cubic equation is known. The other equation does tell you that any extremum lies on $x_2 = x_1$.